# Zero divisors in $[a]_n[b]_n=[0]_n$

Tags: group-theory, equivalence-relations

Precisely,what must be true about n for there to be zero divisors in $ℤ_$ (i.e. elements $[a]_n$ and $[b]_n$ such that $[a]_n[b]_n=[0]_n$ but $[a]_n,[b]_n≠[0]_n$? State your theorem as an 'if and only if' statement. [hint: Consider gcd(a,n) and/or gcd(b,n)]-------This is the problem I posted before.

I figured that $\mathbb{Z}_2$,$\mathbb{Z}_3$,$\mathbb{Z}_4$,$\mathbb{Z}_5$,$\mathbb{Z}_7$ don't have zeor divisors. I think for there to be zero divisiors in$\mathbb{Z}_n$, $n$ should not be prime numbers. But I am not sure what to do with $\mathbb{Z}_4$ because 4 is not prime. It doesn't go with my assumption.

Also, in $\mathbb{Z}_6$, $gcd(2,6)=2$, $gcd(3,6)=3$. In  $\mathbb{Z}_8$,$gcd(2,8)=2$, $gcd(4,8)=4$.. so on. I found that  $gcd(a,n)=a$ and $gcd(b,n)=b$. So is this fact should be on my statement?

Help! Due tomorrow!

Comment: Are you sure about $\mathbb{Z}_4$?  $2\times 2=0$.

Comment: In $\mathbb{Z}_{6}$ we have $4 \cdot 3 = 0$, but gcd$(4,6) = 2 \neq 4$.

Comment: @vadim123 I thought $[a]\not=[b]$. But it is possible I guess.right?

Comment: The condition $[a]\neq[b]$ is unnecessary and makes the problem more difficult.  You just need $n$ to be prime.

Comment: @Arthur You are right! That means in $\mathbb{Z}_8$, 4x6=24, $gcd(6,8)\not=6$ as well. ....

Answer (score 2):

$\textbf{Hint:}$ We have $[a]_n [b]_n = [0]_n$ if and only if $n|ab$ in $\mathbb{Z}$. What does this imply if $n$ is prime? And if $n$ is not prime?

Comment: If $n$ is prime, then $n|a,n|b$, and $gcd(a,n)=1$, and $gcd(b,n)=1$?

Comment: The example $n = 2 = a$, $b = 1$ shows that $n|b$ is not always true. But can you show a slightly weaker result, that still suffices to prove your assumptions about zero divisors in $\mathbb{Z}_n$

Comment: I am so confused.. My assuption is $[a]_n[b]_n=[0]_n$ if only if $n$ is not prime. Since the assumption says $n$ is not prime, I am not sure why I need to consider $n=2$.. What should I consider again?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I meant that your statement "If $n$ is prime, then $n|a$ and $n|b$..." was false, and gave a counterexample. You do know though that when $n$ is prime, $n|ab$ implies that *one* of $n|a$ and $n|b$ is true. With that information you can show that there are no zero divisors in $\mathbb{Z}_n$ when $n$ is prime.

Comment: Thank you Arther. How about this? " There are zero divisors in $\mathbb{Z}_n$ such that, $[a]_n[b]_n=[0]_n$ if only if $n|ab$, $n$ is not prime."

Comment: It is better to split that into two statements. So you would have something like: "There are zero divisors in $\mathbb{Z}_n$ if and only if $n$ is composite, and in that case $[a]_n [b]_n = [0]_n$ if and only if $n|ab$."

Answer (score 1):

If $n$ is compositive, say $ab=n$, then the classes $[a]=x$ and $[b]=y$ will be nonzero, but $xy=0$.

If $n=p$ a prime, we know that $p\mid ab\implies p\mid a$ or $p\mid b$. This means that in $\Bbb Z/(p)$, $$xy=0 \implies x=0 \text{ or  }\; y=0$$ Thus there are no zero divisors.  Moreover, since $p\not\mid a$ is equivalent to $(p,a)=1$, by Bezout we have some $m,n$ for which $an+mp=1$, thus $an=1\mod p$ and every non-zero element has an inverse.

Thus, for $n$ composite $\Bbb Z/(n)$ is not even an integral domain, and for $n=p$ a prime $\Bbb Z/(p)$ is a field.